# Trying to Get ConnectionID For Current Request in SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

My application is a WebApi project using SignalR, similar to this http://blog.johnbrunnings.com/tag/signalr/. I need to get the connectionID in the controller but I'm having trouble working that out as the controller inherits from a generic type.  The definition for my class looks like this:

```
public class PatientListController : ApiControllerWithHub<PatientListHub>
```

So in my code how would I get to the connectionid? I think it is the fact the hub is being used in a generic that is throwing me off but I have been messing with this for a while and cannot figure out how to get to it.

thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
What I really need is access to HubCallerContext, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it appears this is just not possible. Looking at this video http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Belgium-2013/25 at about the 1:04 mark there is a comment about the Hub Caller Context not being available if working with Web API. The solution is to call the hub directly if you need access to the connectionid. Bummer.